# How to get count of key having similar value in javascript object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, mongodb, object

I need to achieve something like this:

```
var data = [
    {
        tag:'A',
        others:'Abc'
    },
    {
        tag:'B',
        others:'Bbc'
    },
    {
        tag:'A',
        others:'Acb'
    }
]
```

I am trying to group tag property having similar value. In given example, i need to group all tag with similar value and put it on another array.Is there way to get something like,

```
var newArray = [{tag:A,count:2}, {tag:B,count:1}]
```

Comment: It would be ten times easier if you just worked with regular objects, and not arrays containing objects. As in `{"A" : 2, "B" : 1 }` etc.

Comment: "similar" is a very, very subjective term. Do you mean "objects with same `tag` value"?

Comment: @Amadan. yes i mean objects with same tag value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Lodash countBy method](https://lodash.com/docs#countBy), you can do something similar to this:

```
var newArray = _.countBy(data, function(val) {
    return val.tag;
});
```

This will output as follow:

```
{ 'A': 2, 'B': 1 }
```

Don't forget to include Lodash to your project

Comment: It is working. But I want to do this with plain javascript as I do  not want to add extra library.

Comment: I wonder why this is accepted as an answer while it does not meet the requirement. The answer that use the Array.reduce does not need any external dependency and provided with a working example.

Answer (score 2):

That why [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) exists:

```js
var data = [
    {
        tag:'A',
        others:'Abc'
    },
    {
        tag:'B',
        others:'Bbc'
    },
    {
        tag:'A',
        others:'Acb'
    }
];

var tmp = data.reduce(function (result, item) {
  result[item.tag] = ++result[item.tag] || 1;
  return result;
}, {});

var count = [];
Object.keys(tmp).forEach(function(key) { count.push({ tag: key, count: tmp[key] }); });

console.log(count);
document.write(JSON.stringify(count, null, 4));
```

Answer (score 0):

i wrote everything from scratch !!!
here's the code ! and the result array is what you wanted ...

```html
<script>
var data= [
             {
              tag:'A',
              others:'Abc'
            },
            {
             tag:'B',
             others:'Bbc'
            },
             {
             tag:'A',
             others:'Acb'
             }

          ] ;
var tags=[];
var flag=0;
var result=[];
for(i=0;i<data.length;i++)
{
 for(j=0;j<tags.length;j++) if(tags[j]==data[i].tag) flag=1;
 if(flag==0) tags.push(data[i].tag);
}          
for(k=0;k<tags.length;k++)
{
 count=0;
 for(m=0;m<data.length;m++)
 {
  if(data[m].tag==tags[k]) count++;
 }
 var obj={};
 obj.tag=tags[k];
 obj.count=count;
 result.push(obj);
}
document.write(result[0].count);
</script>
```